# How to fit 2 hexagonal grid of hexagons in to a square making them as big as possible with out overlapping

Tags: geometry

Back story making a game that needs 2 sets of hexagonal grids inside of a square(this square changes in size). This is what i have so far.

[image: Current Image]

My grid is 9 hexs in height and essential 7 long (5 full and 4 halfs) The side of inner hex is dynamic being = max possible so the outer hex doesn't overlap.

Im trying to figure out how to find the size of a side i'm a bit stuck.

Current approach is to take the center of the screen and draw a point in the middle then make a triangle from the middle to the edge of the square at an angle of 30 Degrees. Which is what the side of my grid ends up as. So, in my head at least, the height and width of this grid should never overlap this line.

Past this im lost and help would be awesome :)